# MongoDB - Adding to a set and incrementing

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to count word usage using MongoDB. My collection currently looks like this:

```
{'_id':###, 'username':'Foo', words:[{'word':'foo', 'count':1}, {'word':'bar', 'count':1}]}
```

When a new post is made, I extract all the new words to an array but I'm trying to figure out to upsert to the words array and increment the count if the word already exists.

In the example above, for example, if the user "Foo" posted "lorem ipsum foo", I'd add "lorem" and "ipsum" to the users words array but increment the count for "foo".

Is this possible in one query? Currently I am using addToSet:

```
'$addToSet':{'words':{'$each':word_array}}
```

But that doesn't seem to offer any way of increasing the words count.

Would very much appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're willing to switch from a list to hash (object), you can atomically do this.

From the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc): "`$inc` ... increments field by the number value if field is present in the object, otherwise sets field to the number value."

```
{ $inc : { field : value } }
```

So, if you could refactor your container and object:

```
words: [
  {
    'word': 'foo',
    'count': 1
  },
  ...
]
```

to:

```
words: {
  'foo': 1,
  'other_word: 2,
  ...
}
```

you could use the operation `update` with:

```
{ $inc: { 'words.foo': 1 } }
```

which would create `{ 'foo': 1 }` if 'foo' doesn't exist, else increment foo.

E.g.:

```
$ db.bar.insert({ id: 1, words: {} });
$ db.bar.find({ id: 1 })
[ 
  {   ...,   "words" : {     },   "id" : 1   }
]
$ db.bar.update({ id: 1 }, { $inc: { 'words.foo': 1 } });
$ db.bar.find({ id: 1 })
[ 
  {   ...,   "id" : 1,   "words" : {   "foo" : 1   }   }
]
$ db.bar.update({ id: 1 }, { $inc: { 'words.foo': 1 } });
$ db.bar.find({ id: 1 })
[ 
  {   ...,   "id" : 1,   "words" : {   "foo" : 2   }   }
]
```

Comment: This only works per word and makes it impossible to do any queries on the words themselves. I'm a little confused on how this is better than dedicated per-word counter tuples. It also comes with the problems I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: A user can throw in an entire word array (changed to ``word: 1`` dict form), and word keys are either added as "1" or incremented. So, it is exactly what the question requested: "I extract all the new words to an array but I'm trying to figure out to upsert to the words array and increment the count if the word already exists." -- and all in one atomic (update) operation, and it's somewhat closer to the question's original structure (right or wrong).

Comment: Fair enough. I still think it's a sub optimal solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do this in a single update with your schema. Your schema is a bit questionable and should probably be converted to having a dedicated collection with word counters, e.g :

```
db.users {_id:###, username:'Foo'}
db.words.counters {_id:###, word:'Word', userId: ###, count: 1}
```

That will avoid quite a few issues such as :

- Running into maximum document size limits
- Forcing mongo to keep moving around your documents as you increase their size

Both scenarios require two updates to do what you want which introduces atomicity issues. Updating per word by looping through word_array is better and safer (and is possible with both solutions).