# Insert or update object element in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With the following schema:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    id:        { type: String,  default: ''       },
    owner:     { type: String,  default: null     },
    votes:    [{ owner: Number, vote: Number      }],
});
```

I want to push an element to the `votes` array if an element with that `owner` doesn't exist. If it does, I want to update that element.

My current code:

```
Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.post_id,
    { $push: { votes: { owner: owner, vote: vote }}},
    { safe: true, upsert: true },
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
);
```

However, this will endlessly insert new elements. Is it possible to do this with one request, or do I have to fall back on multiple requests and if-thens?

Comment: what do you mean by 'this will endlessly insert elements'

Comment: It will add a new element on each request.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: "If the value *is* in the array, `$addToSet` does not modify the array." I'm considering just using an array of subdocuments, that seems like it'd be easier.

Comment: ah I see your issue. you cannot execute an update to some field in a hash contained by an array OR push to that array in the same query, as those updates conflict (changing array size vs toughing some index of an array). i recommend changing the array to a hash as specified here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904928/mongodb-adding-to-a-set-and-incrementing

Comment: Ended up getting it working by just doing a `$pull` followed by a `$push`. Not my preferred solution, but it works.

Comment: that doesn't really make sense to me. it sounds like you indeed wanted `$addToSet`